# ShellExecute not working from IDE but works otherwise

Tags: delphi

I want to create and then open a txt file using the ShellExecute command.

I have used this code for years with Delphi 7 and it worked:

```
function Execute(CONST ExeName, Parameters: string): Boolean;
begin
 Result:= ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(ExeName), PChar(Parameters), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL)> 32;
end;
```

Now, I switched to Windows 7 and the code is not working anymore when it runs from IDE. Delphi shows the CPU window with the caption "CPU-Process unknown (2352)". I close the CU windows and everything works fine until I close the application, when Delphi shows the CPU window one more time.
If I run the app  from outside IDE, it works fine.

Looks like the debugger has something to say to me, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds to me like you have the "[debug spawned processes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Embarcadero_Debuggers)" option turned on. When that's enabled, the debugger interrupts the new process at the earliest possible time. Press the "run" button to let it continue running.

You can confirm this hypothesis the next time you debug your program. Compare the process ID (2352, in your example) with the list of processes shown by Task Manager. Which process in that list matches the process ID reported by the debugger?

Comment: That was it! But I had that option checked for years! With worked with Win 98 and Win XP! 
Isn't better to leave this ON?

1+ and marked as "accepted". 
Many thanks.

Comment: Obviously, it's only better to leave it on if you're going to debug the spawned process. Is that what you want to do? If you don't have the source code or any debug information, there's probably not much you'll be able to do, so you may as well leave it turned off so you don't get interrupted with each new process.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer for your question (I vote for Rob Kennedy & Chris Thornton), but you can write your routine in a more compact way:

```
function Executa(const ExeName, Parameters: string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := 
    (ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(ExeName), Pointer(Parameters), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL) > 32);
end;
```

Note Pointer() instead of PChar() for 4th argument. This is a documented behaviour of PChar/Pointer casts (see help).

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to do that but I was not sure it will work. Because of the lack of time I chose the safe way. Many thanks again!! 1+

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem yesterday with the debugger crashing my application, but running it outside the IDE it would run fine.   I was using packages in my development.

I used [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to verify I found I was loading a copy from another location than expected.   I had two copies of the same BPL floating around.   Once I removed the one I was not compiling I was fine.

Applying that to this problem, I would check to make sure you don't have any copies of compiled code that includes:  .DCU, .DCP, .BPL, .EXE around.   Then I would also make sure you  you can ctrl-click on "ShellExecute" to and see the declaration.   You may have your library path setup in a way that it can't find the source.

Comment: This may be my case. I will check. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Shot in the dark here, but try running the IDE as administrator, and then not as administrator.  That may be a factor. Some users make a shortcut with the administrator option set, so that the auto-update runs successfully. So you may be running the IDE as admin, if you've done that.

Answer (score 1):

Same by me , i solved it by replacing ShellExecute with following:

```
function TformMain.CreateProcessSimple(
  sExecutableFilePath : string )
    : string;

function GetExeByExtension(sExt : string) : string;
var
   sExtDesc:string;
begin
   with TRegistry.Create do
   begin
     try
       RootKey:=HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT;
       if OpenKeyReadOnly(sExt) then
       begin
         sExtDesc:=ReadString('') ;
         CloseKey;
       end;
       if sExtDesc <>'' then
       begin
         if OpenKeyReadOnly(sExtDesc + '\Shell\Open\Command') then
         begin
           Result:= ReadString('') ;
         end
       end;
     finally
       Free;
     end;
   end;
end;
var
  pi: TProcessInformation;
  si: TStartupInfo;
  fapp: string;
begin
  fapp:=GetExeByExtension(ExtractFileExt(sExecutableFilePath));
  FillMemory( @si, sizeof( si ), 0 );
  si.cb := sizeof( si );
  if Pos('%1',fApp)>0 then begin
    sExecutableFilePath:=StringReplace(fapp,'%1',sExecutableFilePath,[rfReplaceAll]);
  end else begin
    sExecutableFilePath:=fApp+' "'+sExecutableFilePath+'"';
  end;
  CreateProcess(
    Nil,

    // path to the executable file:
    PChar( sExecutableFilePath ),

    Nil, Nil, False,
    NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, Nil, Nil,
    si, pi );

  // "after calling code" such as
  // the code to wait until the
  // process is done should go here  

  CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
  CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
end;
```

Comment: You need to call CloseHandle ONLY if CreateProcess is successful.

Answer (score 0):

ShellExecuteW solve my problems (XE2/Win7/32bit) with "debug spawned processes" option turned off
:)
mybe because strings and pchar are wide pointer from 2010